# track "message sent to deallocated instance" via instruments

Tags: iphone, xcode, exc-bad-access, instruments

In XCode 4.2, I need some help with Instruments to track down cause of EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  After enabling the NSZombie flag, I see the following on console when the app crashes on the device.

```
*** -[__NSArrayM removeObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8674e30
```

I used Instruments, but don't see the profile for Zombie. I used Allocations profile, but quickly got lost. I enabled ARC (in a hope to get rid of alloc/retain/release) for the app - but still have the same problem.

How do I use Instruments to track this down?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Edited my question...it is for iPhone, using XCode 4.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have any *UIScrollView*s in your view hierarchy and are you sending them messages like scrollToVisibleRect:animated:?

If so, try to pass NO for the animated parameter. It appears that iOS5 may have some issues with scroll views and embedded animations. The same exact crash you are seeing had been driving me crazy for a few days (with no call stack available) and I finally narrowed it down to the scroll view call.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Raffaello... No, I don't have UIScrollView, but do have UITableViews.  I think I am using scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:  method though.  I have made the change and in my brief testing, the crash has not happened.  I will test extensively on the device and post the status again.  THANKS, this may be a lifesaver.

Comment: After making this changes, I have not seen the crash.  Again, thanks, Raffaello.

Comment: (I usually hate these kinds of comments but) THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! Just spent an hour trying to figure out why I was getting a random NSArray overrelease and couldn't find it anywhere in my code. Turning off animation on my row select call fixed the crash! Yet another annoying iOS5 bug...

Comment: You don't need to set the animation to NO.  If you set the UITableView's delegate to nil in ViewWillUnload, that will resolve the issue.  The issue is that Core Animation is retaining the scrollview for the animation, and then trying to send a delegate message.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. At first I have used the Raffaello Colasante's solution and passed `NO` to `scrollRectToVisible:animated:`. But then I've noticed that this method processed on another thread.
You should check, whether you call `[uitableview scrollRectToVisible: CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:YES]` on Main Thread (All ui actions should be performed on main thread). I change my code so to call it on Main Thread.

From:

```
//method called not from main thread
...
[someObjectInstance setOptionalActions:optActions];
```

To:

```
//method called not from main thread
...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //now method called from main thread
    [someObjectInstance setOptionalActions:optActions];
});
```

Note: (setOptionalActions:) call -> (**scrollRectToVisible:animated:**)

Now problem fixed.

P.S. Instead of use [Grand Central Dispatch(GCD)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html), you can use [another approach](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a):

```
@implementation SomeObjectClass  
...
- (void) setOptionalActions:(NSArray *) actionsArray {
    ... // handling of array
    [myTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:YES];
}
...
@end

//method called not from main thread, but will be performed on main thread
[someObjectInstance performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setOptionalActions:) withObject:optionalActions waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Profile or run with instruments(command+I) then use the Leaks tool.
[image: Leaks tool screenshot]

Inside click on the leaks part and check the Gather Leaked memory content checkbox.
[image: properties screenshot]
Good luck.

Comment: Hello Ariel, thanks for the pointer about Instruments - it has always puzzled me.  I guess I should buckle my belt and get down to using/understanding it.  The problem turned out to be quite trivial...and I ended up spending 2 of the 4 wkend days! Love this community.  THANKS TO ALL WHO REPLIED....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8281871/296446) on using the zombies profilier on the simulator.  Basically you should be able to use the profilier by:

1. Change the Run mode to profile.
2. Select Zombies from the list.
3. When it caches the zombie, double click on the stack trace on the right to see variaous parts of the objects lifecycle.

Comment: My version of Instruments - 4.2 (4233) - does not have the Zombie profile that you mention in your link.  Is it hidden somewhere or do I not have the latest version of Instruments.  I am using XCode 4.2.

Comment: Dont open instruments on its own, close it fist.  Then launch XCode in profile mode and make it launch instruments.  You should see the option when it first loads.  Otherwise what compiler and debugger are you using (llvm / gdb)?

Comment: Also you can only see the zombie option if you are running on the simulator not the device.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Command:

```
Shell malloc_history process_id memory
```

eg. Shell malloc_history process_id 0x11afab80

Enable Following for the same 1)MallocstackLogging 2) NsDebugEnabled 3)NSZombieEnabled

this will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, Rahul.....1. Could not find how to enable NSDebugEnabled.  2. What is the hex number above? Is it the address of the deallocated instance? Why is it preceded with process_id then?  3.  I tried the command in the XCode's console, and got error - 'shell' is not a valid command

Comment: Hex Number is memory address. In your case it is "0x8674e30" . Please go through the tutorial on http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

Comment: I just went thru it - and it is referring to features in Xcode 2.x -some of them are not present in Xcode 4.2 (like NSDebugEnabled). I got a little confused there.

Comment: You have to go into the "Get info" contextual menu of your executable (inside the "Executables" group in the left panel of XCode). Then go in the arguments tab. You can add the environnement variables that you specified above in the box at the bottom ("Variables to set in the env.".

Comment: Thanks - I will explore that.